# Too many data in my matrix implementation >> slow and unable to submit so much data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need a kind of matrix to edit values. Here is my result so far:

[image]

So I have a very big kind of table (composed of several textboxes). I still need to add caption text in heading but this is just a test at this time.

I have 2 problems with my solution:

1. When I focus on numbers in the matrix to change it, it takes time to focus on these textboxes.
2. When I click submit, I got an error because there are too many elements to return.

I try with less data and it works better: quicker changing focus in different textboxes and the submit works just fine.

Here are my controller actions:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var dto = _requestServiceClient.GetMatrices();
        var vm = new List<MatrixVM>();
        var viewModel = new MatrixIndexViewModel();
        Mapper.Map(dto, vm);
        viewModel.Matrix = vm;
        return View(viewModel); 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MatrixIndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Here is the model I use:

```
public class MatrixIndexViewModel
{
    public List<MatrixVM> Matrix { get; set; }
}

public class MatrixVM
{
    public int      MatrixID { get; set; }
    public int      OriginStopID { get; set; }
    public string   OriginStopText { get; set; }
    public int      DestinationStopID { get; set; }
    public string   DestinationStopText { get; set; }
    public int      NumberOfDays { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my view:

```
@model PLATON.WebUI.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.Matrix.MatrixIndexViewModel
@using PLATON.WebUI.App_LocalResources

@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.Admin.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = UserResource.Matrix;
    double nbrStops = Math.Sqrt(Model.Matrix.Count());
    Html.EnableClientValidation(false);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{     
    for (int count = 0; count < Model.Matrix.Count(); count++)
    {
        if (count % nbrStops == 0)
        {   
            // Displaying heading text for each lines         
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Matrix[count].OriginStopText)
        }

        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Matrix[count].MatrixID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Matrix[count].OriginStopID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Matrix[count].DestinationStopID)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Matrix[count].NumberOfDays, new { style = "width:13px" })

        if (count % nbrStops == nbrStops - 1) 
        {
            // Proceed next line
            @:<br /> 
        }
    }

    <div class="submit_block"> 
        <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Enregistrer" /> 
    </div> 
}
```

Do you have an idea of a better implementation? Maybe a bettier idea is to have a "read-only" matrix and be able to click on elements to edit it in a jquery dialog. What do you think?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? And how?

Comment: Yes, to fix this problem I do as I suggested myself: have a "read-only" matrix and be able to click on elements to edit it in a jquery dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would go with a `<table>` to show the data and on the `onclick/onmouseenter` of every cell I will show a Textbox to accept the input.

You can think of opening a popup so you can post a value at the time to the controller or you can substitute the cell text with a TextBox and log only the values changed in a list of input hidden.